# Counting unique states in 3d tic tac toe with 6 moves

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am doing some probability review and came across in interesting question I can't quite figure out how to do. The question is asking for a 3x3x3 tic tac toe board with three players a,b,c with taking turns in order. How many different states are there if there are 6 moves made. Now, from my understanding there first move A has 27 different possibilities, then B has 26 possibilities and C has 25 possibilities. Now here is where I get a bit confused on the next Move A has 24 choices, but now there is overcounting introduced since he could have switched move 1 and 2 and ended up in the same place and so on for the next playyers. I'm trying to find a general formula, but just cant seem to be able to find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the order of moves doesn't matter since each player will take two, no one can win in six moves, and we are not assessing the likely hood that a player will choose a particular place on each move.  We just need to count the distinct ways of placing pairs of tokens of each player onto the grid.

There are $\frac{27\times 26}2$ places player-a can take, $\frac{25\times 24}2$ places player-b can take, and then $\frac{23\times 22}2$ player-c can take.  That is $26\,640\,900$ distinct outcomes.

---

**PS:**  This is a **multinomial coefficient**, one which counts the ways to select $27$ distinct items into heaps of $2$, $2$, $2$, and $21$.

$$\dbinom{27}{2,2,2,21} \;=\; \dfrac{27!}{2!\,2!\,2!\,21!}$$